# Angular page not showing JSON data from Node backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mean-stack

I'm totally new to modern web development and have been learning the MEAN stack from online tutorials. I'm just writing a simple todo app that allows CRUD operations. This is with the MEAN stack (Mongo database via Mongolab) and `npm` and `bower` as package managers - no scaffolding tools or cloning an existing app. This is my first time with Node and Angular.

I'm running into problems with displaying my HTML page using Angular. Here are the relevant files:

`app.js` for the backend (including only the relevant sections):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var morgan = require('morgan');
var db = require('./db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended' : 'true'}));

require('./backend/todo_rest')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

`todo_rest.js`:

```
var TodoSchema = require('./todo_schema');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(_app) {
    _app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
         TodoSchema.find({}, function(err, todos) {
            console.log('API GET; data: ' + todos);
            if(err)
                return res.status(500).send("The todos could not be retrieved from the database!");
            return res.json(todos);
        });
    });

    _app.get('*', function(req, res){
         res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/views/index.html'));
     });
};
```

`app.js` for the front end:

```
var app = angular.module('todosApp', []);

app.controller('todosController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.todos = {};

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/todos'
    }).then(function (success) {
        console.log(success.data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Angular GET error: ' + error.data);
    });
});
```

and `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todosApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todos App</title>
    <script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>     // <-- this is the frontend's app.js
</head>
<body ng-controller="todosController">
<div>
    <span>Total: {{todos.length}}</span>
    <ul ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <li>Name: {{todo.title}}, {{todo.completed}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although I do want to support full CRUD, right now I just want the HTML to display all the todos from the database. Here are the current problems:

- When I launch the page via `localhost:3000`, I get the HTML but Angular elements like `{{todos.length}}` are displayed as is, instead of being replaced by the evaluated values. Basically, when I launch that page, I want all the todos to be displayed as a list by calling the `/api/todos` endpoint that I've exposed in my backend. I've checked that the `console.log` in the frontend's `app.js` isn't triggered.
- When I launch `localhost:3000/api/todos`, the JSON result is displayed in the browser instead of any HTML. Do I need to use routing in Angular to display a different view for each end point in the same page?

Comment: are you getting `angualr is undefined` error or something like this at your console?

Comment: @Pengyy Nope, nothing like that. I actually see messages which show that the js files in the <script> lines have been retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {{todos.length}} are displayed as is, instead of being replaced by the evaluated values.

If you see this, it means your angularjs app is not bootstraped successfully. See errors at your console for further fix actions.

add `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` to your app.js(nodejs) in order to serve static files.

> I want all the todos to be displayed as a list by calling the /api/todos

you have to set result from `$http.get` to `$scope.todos`

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/todos'
}).then(function (success) {
  console.log(success.data);
  $scope.todos = success.data;      // <-------- set result to $scope.todos
}, function (error) {
  console.log('Angular GET error: ' + error.data);
});
```

move `ng-repeat` to `li`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">Name: {{todo.title}}, {{todo.completed}}</li>
</ul>
```

> When I launch localhost:3000/api/todos, the JSON result is displayed in the browser instead of any HTML. Do I need to use routing in Angular to display a different view for each end point in the same page?

You mean access `localhost:3000/api/todos` at your browser directly? you don't have to this, `$http.get` will do the work and retrieve the result. And currently you don't need `routing` since you just have one simple page.

Comment: I tried this, still the same result. On the console, I see several GET statements for files listed in index.html's <script> tags. The console.log before $scope.todos isn't triggered either.

Comment: @Cygnus have you checked @Mukesh Sharma's answer? maybe your app.js isn't loaded to browser at all.  you can add `console.log()` before `$scope.todos={}` to confirm.

Comment: @Cygnus also make sure there isn't `404` errors at `network` tag.

Comment: yeah, that console.log isn't executed either. I've added a comment to Mukesh's answer.

Comment: No luck :( I tried express.static(__dirname + '/client') as well as express.static('client') in addition to just __dirname as the argument. Does it have to be the path of app.js or index.html?

Comment: @Cygnus the static path should **include** `index.html` and `app.js` and `bower_component` folder.

Comment: that worked!!! Wow, wish this were easier to find online. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Cygnus glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have not configured your Express server to serve static content, that's why your browser is not able to load `app.js`. Hence, angular app is not initialized.

Use `express.static` to load static content.

Comment: Hmm, based on @Pengyy's comment above, this seems to be the case. Could you add an example of how to use express.static? I've added this - app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/views'))); - but it doesn't help. Do I have to provide a REST path for it?

Comment: can you share your directory structure?

Comment: I was able to get it to work, express.static was needed as you mentioned. Thanks a lot!